# How do I get the return values form the callback functions in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using Angular,NodeJS, MYSql

i need to get the return values of the mysql query in other function. is that posible

as like the following code

i need to get the details from the query from other function, but i cannot able to get the details of user address.

any solution for get the details?

thank you

```
exports.getUserDetails= (req, res) => {
    sql = 'SELECT * FROM users ';
    connection.query(sql, (error, results, fileds) => {
        if(error) {
            res.send({
                "success" : false,
                "message" : "Error : "+error.message
            });
        }
        else {
            if(results.length >0) { 
                let users = [];
                results.forEach(user => {
                    let addressDetas = this.getUserAddress(user.id);
                    let userdata = {}
                    userdata = user;
                    userdata.address = addressDetas; 
                    users.push(userdata);
                });
                res.send({
                    "success" : true,
                    "message" : "No Record ",
                "result" : users
                });
            }
            else {
                res.send({
                    "success" : true,
                    "message" : "No Record ",
                    "result" : results
                });
            }
        }
    });
}

exports.getUserAddress= (userid) => {
sql = 'SELECT * FROM address WHERE user_id = "'+userid+'" ';
    connection.query(sql, (error, results, fileds) => {
        if(error) {
            return error;
        }
        else {
            return results;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You might consider using consistent indentation when writing code - it'll make reading and debugging it much easier, not only for potential answerers, but for you as well, when we can all see the `{` `}` blocks and their nesting level at a glance, rather than having to carefully pick through each line just to pick up on the logical paths.

Answer (score 0):

It's not `getUserAddress` that is returning, it's the callback passed in to `connection.query`. if you want to capture the results of the query, you need to pass in your own callback function (conventionally as the last argument) to `getUserAddress`. However, there have been significant syntax features to help you write the code in more synchronous looking style, notably `Promise` and the `async` and `await` keywords. If you rewrite your function using these, you will be able to use it as you intend. Something like:

```
const until = require ('util'):

exports.getUserAddress = async function (userId) {
  const SQL = select etc....'';
  const query = until.promisify(connection.query);
  return await query(sql,);
}
```

And use it like this:

```
async function printAddress() {
  const address =await getUserAddress(123);
  console.log(address);
}
```